# Open link in WebView when tapping a navigation drawer item

Tags: android-studio, webview, navigation, navigation-drawer

Followed a tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/navigation-drawer-in-android/) to create a navigation drawer and worked fine. The webview also loads when the app starts.

My Landing page loads when the app starts:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/updates.php");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());}
```

Url should open when a navigation item was selected:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/search.php");
            return true;
        }
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
              //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Drawer Items is located at res>menu>navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

      <item
         android:id="@+id/nav_search"
         android:title="Search" />
</menu>
```

Tried:

```
String url = "http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/search.php";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

And followed this from developer.android.com:

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_search:
    String url="http://192.168.43.105/public_html/central/search.php";
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I didn't get any error when starting the app. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For external URL try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

If you want to web browser open in your activity try this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

and If you want to use the zoom control in your browser then add this also:

```
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but the link is still not opening. I added and edited some lines on the post. I also tried removing the url on onCreate but still not working.

Comment: Are your initial updates URL loading successfully?